# Prove if $f(x)=\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$ is a continuous par function, then $a_{n}=0$ for all $n$ odd.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

i need help with this exercise:

Prove if $f(x)=\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$ is a continuous par function, then $a_{n}=0$ for all $n$ odd.

I try this:

If f is continuous par function, then $f^{(n)}$ is impar when $n$ is odd, We know $a_{n}=\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ but i can't conclude $a_{n}=0$

Comment: Hint: for any even function $f(x)-f(-x)=0$.

Comment: Note: impar means odd.

Answer (score 3):

I think that
$a_n = 0$
when $n$ is even, not odd.
For example,
$f(x) = x$
is odd.

If $f(x)$ is even,
then $a_n = 0$
for odd $n$.

Here's why.

If
$f(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}
$
is odd,
then $f(x) = -f(-x)$
so
$-f(-x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}-a_{n}(-x)^{n}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}(-1)^{n+1}x^{n}
$.

Therefore
$a_n = a_{n}(-1)^{n+1}$.

If $n$ is odd,
then
$(-1)^{n+1} = 1$,
so this becomes
$a_n = a_n$,
which doesn't tell us anything.

If $n$ is even,
then
$(-1)^{n+1} = -1$,
so this becomes
$a_n = -a_n$,
which implies that
$a_n = 0$.